# Running large dataset causes timeout

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a Spark application that is relatively simple. Generally, the logic looks like this:

```
val file1 = sc.textFile("s3://file1/*")
val file2 = sc.textFile("s3://file2/*")
// map over files
val file1Map = file1.map(word => (word, "val1"))
val file2Map = file2.map(differentword => (differentword, "val2"))
val unionRdd = file1Map.union(file2Map)
val groupedUnion = unionRdd.groupByKey()
val output = groupedUnion.map(tuple => {
    // do something that requires all the values, return new object
    if(oneThingIsTrue) tuple._1 else "null"
}).filter(line => line != "null")
output.saveAsTextFile("s3://newfile/")
```

The question has to do with this not working when I run it with larger datasets. I can run it without errors when the Dataset is around 700GB. When I double it to 1.6TB, the job will get halfway before timing out. Here is the Err log:

```
INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Don't have map outputs for shuffle 0, fetching them
INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Doing the fetch; tracker endpoint = NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark://MapOutputTracker@172.31.4.36:39743)
ERROR MapOutputTrackerWorker: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
    org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [800 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.network.timeout
```

I have tried increasing the network timeout to both 800 seconds and 1600 seconds but all this does is delay the error for longer. I am running the code on 10r4.2xl which have 8 cores each and 62gb RAM. I have EBS setup to have 3TB storage. I am running this code via Zeppelin in Amazon EMR.

Can anyone help me debug this? The CPU usage of the cluster will be close to 90% the whole time until it gets halfway and it drops back to 0 completely. The other interesting thing is that it looks like it fails in the second stage when it is shuffling. As you can see from the trace, it is doing the fetch and never gets it.

Here is a photo from Ganglia.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what caused this but I was able to get around it by coalescing the unionRdd and then grouping that result. Changing the above code to:

```
...
// union rdd is 30k partitions, coalesce into 8k
val unionRdd = file1Map.union(file2Map)
val col = unionRdd.coalesce(8000) 
val groupedUnion = col.groupByKey()
...
```

It might not be efficient, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

replace groupbykey with reduceByKey or aggregateByKey or combineByKey.

[groupByKey](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L492) must bring all like keys onto the same worker and this can cause an out of memory error. Not sure why there isn't a warning on using this function